# React-Redux: Best Implementation for different display modes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently working on a React-Redux Dashboard WebApp. This Dashboard offers several levels of details. They are called: `display_modes` and have a value from 1 to 3. Mode 1 is with less details, and mode 3 is with more details. The `display_mode` is stored in the Redux store.

My app also has several "pages" which are reachable through different routes. Each page has its own component. Let's say `Home` and `Profile`.

According to the `display_mode`, the architecture of the components will be completely different. Thus, since I don't want to have so many conditions inside my component, I want to have a different component for each mode: `Home1` `Home2` and `Home3` (same for `Profile`).

I would like to know which is the best way to do this? (in terms of code quality and performance).

I thought of doing something like that:

```
const Home = ({ mode }) => {
    return (
        {mode == 1 && <Home1 />}
        {mode == 2 && <Home2 />}
        {mode == 3 && <Home3 />}
    );
}
```

I also thought of doing it this way:

```
import store from "./getStore";
if(store.getState().mode === 1) module.exports = require('./Home1');
if(store.getState().mode === 2) module.exports = require('./Home2');
if(store.getState().mode === 3) module.exports = require('./Home3');
```

Where getStore exports the redux store and the HomeX files return the relevant component.

I am actually scared that the first version would not be as good in terms of performance because it imports all of the components before rendering. What do you think?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Passing props to the component is more conventional than exporting based on Redux state.  You may consider that you don't need three separate Home components as well.  Passing props to a flexible component or creating a Home HOC might be more attractive solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed it makes more sense to pass it as props, but in my case it is a value that can be modified in other components (it is a user setting). So I understand that you are suggesting the first version that I wrote? Or do you have a more beautiful way to write it (knowing that I would have a similar logic for other components).

Comment: Yes, the use the first version.  I'm pretty sure there is a way to improve what you've got overall, though.  Having the separate versions of the components is unlikely to be the best way to go.  Maybe open another question regarding how to better reuse your Home component.